# discord.py bot not replying on command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

i want to make  command that look like you killed someone

here my code:

```
@client.command()
async def pew_pew(ctx, targetGuy):
  await ctx.reply(targetGuy, "has been pew pew")
```

bbut when i try the command it say

> Ignoring exception in command pew_pew:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 994, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 886, in invoke
> await self.prepare(ctx)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 820, in prepare
> await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 726, in _parse_arguments
> transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 560, in transform
> raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
> discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: targetGuy is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: did u add the user name as argument while using that command in discord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not setting the target when using that command. Try using the command and using a specific user id or name.